# select data from excel using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am writing a script to select specific data from a `.xlsx` file using PowerShell v7.0.

The Excel worksheet contains the following data:

```
+------------------------------+------------------+---------+
|           Company            |     Contact      | Country |
+------------------------------+------------------+---------+
| Alfreds Futterkiste          | Maria Anders     | x       |
| Centro comercial Moctezuma   | Francisco Chang  | x       |
| Ernst Handel                 | Roland Mendel    | x       |
| Island Trading               | Helen Bennett    | UK      |
| Laughing Bacchus Winecellars | Yoshi Tannamuri  | Canada  |
| Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti | Giovanni Rovelli | x       |
+------------------------------+------------------+---------+
```

To get a representation of the table that you can copy and paste as-is into an Excel sheet, click on `Show code snippet` and then on `Run code snippet`.

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What i did:

```
$Output = [object][order]@{
                Name = $WorkSheet.Range("C1:C1000").Formula = "=x"
        }
        $Output
```

Expected result: 
list of company where Country = 'x'

**Alfreds Futterkiste

Centro comercial Moctezuma

Ernst Handel

Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **consider using specialized PowerShell modules** to interact with Excel workbooks - e.g., [`ImportExcel`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel).

If that is not an option, and you must use **[Excel's COM Automation Application interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application?view=excel-pia)**, as in your question:

The following (easily tweaked) code assumes that your table is in the first worksheet of an `.xlsx` file (and that that worksheet contains nothing else).

```
# Note: Be sure to specify a *full path*
$xlFile = Convert-Path 'sample.xlsx'

& {

 $xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

 $ws = $xl.Workbooks.Open($xlFile).Worksheets(1)

 $ws.UsedRange.Rows | 
   Where-Object   { $_.Cells(1, 3).Value2 -eq 'x' } |
   ForEach-Object { $_.Cells(1, 1).Value2 }

 $xl.Quit()

}
```

Note: `.Worksheets(1)` is short for `.Worksheets.Item(1)`, and `.Cells(1, 3)` for `.Cells.Item(1, 3)`. In earlier versions of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), only the latter, explicit form was supported,<sup>[1]</sup> but since (at least) v7.2 the shorthand form works too (it always did in *Window PowerShell*).

---

<sup>[1] See [GitHub issue #4554](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4554) for background information.</sup>